# Combine Linq join

Tags: c#, linq

How can I combine these together?
job.Result?.Name needs to equal Scene7ImageSet1 or Scene7ImageSet2.

```
(from job in jobs
      join product in products on job.Result?.Name equals product?.Scene7ImageSet1
 select product.MediaSet = job.Result).ToList();

(from job in jobs
      join product in products on job.Result?.Name equals product?.Scene7ImageSet1
 select product.MediaSet = job.Result).ToList();
```

Comment: Your two queries are identical? Also the syntax of the `select` does not look right?

Comment: @NetMage neither does the first. They are both assigning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply where clause with `||` operator.

```
(job.Result?.Name==product?.Scene7ImageSet1 || job.Result?.Name==product?.Scene7ImageSet1)
```

The query looks like;

```
 (from job in jobs
 from product in products
 where (job.Result?.Name==product?.Scene7ImageSet1 || job.Result?.Name==product?.Scene7ImageSet1)
 select new{...}).ToList();
```

Comment: `from`, not `join`

Comment: Thank you. So it should be?
 (from job in jobs
 from product in products

Comment: It was just a typo. Sorry for this.